# App accessible via port 3000 after deploy to server

Tags: django, nginx, docker-compose, dockerfile, port

I have a django app running in docker containers (please see docker compose and dockerfile below). I have removed port exposure from my docker-compose however when i deploy the code onto an ubuntu server, I can still access the app via port 3000. I am also using nginx to do the proxing (see nginx file below).

```
services:
  rabbitmq:
    restart: always
    image: rabbitmq:3.7
    ...

  db:
    restart: always
    image: mongo:4
    ...

  cam_dash:
    restart: always
    build: .
    command: python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:3000
    ...

  celery:
    restart: always
    build: .
    command: celery -A dashboard worker -l INFO -c 200
    ...

  celery_beat:
    restart: always
    build: .
    command: celery beat -A dashboard -l info --scheduler django_celery_beat.schedulers:DatabaseScheduler
    ...
```

```
FROM python:3.7

COPY requirements.txt /
RUN pip3 install -r /requirements.txt

ADD ./ /dashboard
WORKDIR /dashboard

COPY ./docker-entrypoint.sh /docker-entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /docker-entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/docker-entrypoint.sh"]

EXPOSE 3000
```

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;
        server_name _;
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;

        root         /var/www/html;
        index        index.html;
}

server {
        listen 443;
        server_name camonitor.uct.ac.za;

        ssl on;
        ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/wildcard.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/wildcard.key;
        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;

        location / {
                root   /var/www/html;
                index  index.html;
        }

        location /dash/ {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000/dash/;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        }
        ...
```

I am expecting that if I try access https://example.com:3000/dash/, it should not be accessible. https://example.com/dash/ works just fine.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should prevent access to port 3000 using the system's firewall.
I had same issue hosting more than one web server on same machine and proxying with Nginx, I solved using this port configuration in docker-compose.yml, binding the port only to localhost, maybe you could apply same configuration to python server.

> "127.0.0.1:3000:3000"

```
version: '3'
services:
  myService:
    image: "myService/myService:1"
    container_name: "myService"
    ports:
      - "127.0.0.1:3000:3000"
```